# VHDL std_logic_vector indexing with "downto"

Tags: indexing, vhdl

I would like to set bits of a std_logic_vector separately in order to easily set comments for individual bits or group of bits. Here is what I have:

```
signal DataOut : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
DataOut <= (                        5=>'1',     -- Instruction defined
                                    4=>'1',     -- Data length control bit, high=8bit bus mode selected
                                    3=>'1',     -- Display Line Number ctrl bit, high & N3 option pin to VDD=3 lines display
                                    2=>'0',     -- Double height font type control byte, not selected
                                    1 downto 0=>"01",   -- Select Instruction table1
                                    others=>'0' -- for bits 6,7
                                    );
```

However, I've a problem with the "downto" statement, I get the following error using Xilinx ISE:

```
Type std_ulogic does not match with a string litteral
```

Any solution to avoid  using the equivalent

```
1=>'0',
0=>'1',
```

and to allow me to set bits by block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assignment `X downto Y => 'A'` is correct when A is a element of array. For example, this snippet is correct:

```
1 downto 0 => '1',
```

And this snippet is wrong:

```
1 downto 0 => "01",
```

Therefore, your assignment is illegal. As your code, you can assign as:

```
DataOut <= (                        5 downto 3 =>'1',     
                                    2 downto 1 =>'0',     
                                    0 => '1',  
                                    others=>'0' 
                                    );
```

If you want to access/assign by a feild of array, you can use concatenation:

```
DataOut <= Something_0 & Something_1 & "01";
```

While `Something_*` is `std_logic_vector`

Answer (score 3):

Another answer is concatenation using '&', which loses the clarity of named association, though you can recover some of the self-documentation with named constants

```
constant Instr_Defined : std_ulogic := '1';
constant Bus_8_Bit     : std_ulogic := '1';

DataOut <= "00" & Instr_Defined
                & Bus_8_Bit
                & '1'     -- description
                & '0'     -- ditto
                & "01";
```

Another answer is to write a function to create instructions : this can make the main flow very simple and clear, while keeping the instruction encodings entirely separate and in a single place, e.g. in a package used wherever you need to know the instruction formats (perhaps in an assembler as well as the CPU)

```
DataOut <= Encode_Instruction(Instr_Defined, Bus_8_Bit, Font_Mode);
```

It's OK to use any of the preceding techniques, however verbose, in the function body. The more explicit and detailed the better; it isn't cluttering up the main design so you'll rarely look at it unless changing instruction formats.

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```
DataOut(7 downto 6)<="00";
DataOut(5)<='1';
DataOut(4)<='1';
DataOut(3)<='1';
DataOut(2)<='1';
DataOut(1 downto 0)<="01";
```

Comment: Yes, it is a solution, but the same kind as `1=>'0',
0=>'1',`. It is better, but not perfect yet...

Comment: if you just want to initialize the vector, e.g. set bits 1..0 to zero, you can use ",...1 downto 0=> '0',..." (this works same as "others").