# how to make std_logic_vector consist of std_logic_vectorin vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have such signal:

```
sw : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

and now I want to make another one, which will have it as upper bits, 1 the rest:

```
std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (7 downto 0 => sw, others => '1');
```

but it won't compile. any help please? I don't want to do it bit by bit.

Comment: You haven't specified which VHDL tool, which can be important to whether or not slices are supported in aggregates using a -2008 compliant mode. That aggregate would either be (sw, others => '1') for positional association or (31 downto 24 => sw, others => '1') for named association assuming a target subtype of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0). See *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff* Peter Ashenden and Jim Lewis, 6.4 Slices in Aggregates, or IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates. Slices in array aggregates may not be supported in your tool chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where should go this smaller signal, but you probably want to do this:

```
signal sw: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal big: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

big <= sw & x"FFFFFF";
```

This will assign sw vector to 8 most significant bits of big vector, and '1' to rest of bits. Write in comments, if you want to do something else.

Comment: I want something similar but actually sw is 6 downto 0, so it becomes little ugly your way and I prefer previous notation if possible....

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You would have to assign each bit separately.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336875/vhdl-std-logic-vector-indexing-with-downto), there is good explanation of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is assign a signal -which is variable- to another signal during initialization. What do you expect to happen?

I.e. at the moment you *define* a signal, you can only *initialize* it. If you want to *assign* something to the signal, you have to write a *declaration*.

- definition -> initialization
- declaration -> assignment

So in this case you can define `big` a larger range, and fix the constant bits in initialization

```
signal big : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) => (others => '1');
```

And when you want to assign `sw` to any part of `big`, do that after the `begin`.

```
big(31 downto 24) <= sw;
```

or

```
big(7 downto 0) <= sw;
```

etc. The bits you initialized as '1' will be overwritten by the assignment.